# Accord.net 3.8 AdaBoost Learner delegate

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net, adaboost

I'm so happy to Accord.net 3.8 version finally released and of course AdaBoost class had clean Decide and Learn methods.
Please give me an example about new AdaBoost class or tell us more about datatype ISupervisedLearning
I'd wrote some samples like this but can't understand clearly what is that type or how it works?

```
    public void Learn_Internal(double[][] aadMlInpFv, int[] anMlOutGt)
    {
        if (aadMlInpFv == null || aadMlInpFv.Length == 0) return;
        try
        {
            if (m_teacher == null)
            {
                m_oModel_Adaboost = new Boost<DecisionStump>();
                m_teacher = new AdaBoost<DecisionStump>()
                {
                    MaxIterations = 100,
                    Tolerance = 1e-10
                };
            }
            m_teacher.Learner = U_LearnerFunc;
            m_oModel_Adaboost = m_teacher.Learn(aadMlInpFv, anMlOutGt); // error should be zero.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private ISupervisedLearning<DecisionStump, double[], int> U_LearnerFunc(AdaBoostParameters arg)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

- If i use old way DecisionStump OnCrate(double[] weights), gives me
  warning in compile time and in runtime give me an exception!
- Of course i like new way for do it.

Answer (score 0):

It was already resolved by using:

```
m_teacher = new AdaBoost<DecisionStump>()
                    {
                        Learner = (p) => new ThresholdLearning(),
                        MaxIterations = 100,
                        Tolerance = 1e-10
                    };
```